# read_stream for Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I'm developing an app in Cordova (HTML5 cross device app). I need the permission read_stream to show the latest posts on a user's timeline. However, according to [the guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1) this is not allowed:

> read_stream
>
> Provides access to read the posts in a person's News Feed, or the posts on their Profile.
>
> Review
>   If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.
>
> Limited Use
>
> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

After Googling I found at this is introduced with v2.0 with the Graph API.
But, how is it possible that there are several 3rd party apps for Android, like [Fast for Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.fastfacebook.com&hl=en)? Or do they just pay a lot of money to FB...
The only way I guess is to say that the app is for Firefox OS, because there is no native app for Firefox OS. But, some day they might find out that the app has been released for Android as well.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

They are probably using an older App created before end of April 2014 - so they can still use v1.0 and don´t need to go through the review process. They will not be able to use read_stream after April 2015, that´s when they will have to go through review.

I don´t think Firefox OS counts, because there IS a native Facebook client: You can just open www.facebook.com in the Browser.

Comment: Your app also need to replicate the Facebook app. And why you want to replicate the Facebook app on Android I have no idea

Comment: yeah, keep in mind that there IS a native facebook app, so instead of seeing their stream in your app, users can just open the official facebook client instead.

Comment: I am not planning to replicate the Facebook app. I want to show feeds from multiple sources (Twitter, Facebook, ...) in one overview. But, so it seems, this is not allowed for FB at least.

Comment: yeah, at least not anymore. a lot of tools will stop working after april 2015 - although, only those who are using private profile data. page tools will still be no problem.